# Using Windows named pipes between Win7 and XP

Tags: winapi, named-pipes

I have written a C application to run on a small wireless network (linksys router).  The application uses named pipes.  When the server is a Win 7 machine and the client is a XP (Pro, SP3) machine the named pipes connection works fine and the app runs perfectly.  However, when I swap roles and make the server the XP machine and the client the Win 7 machine, the pipe fails.

I have tried turning off the firewall on the XP machine and that doesn't solve the problem.

File and print sharing between the two machines works fine.

Any suggestions would be most gratefully accepted.

Comment: see [Problem migrating ConnectNamedPipe() from XP to Win 7][1]. Worked for us in C#. There is also a code sample in C++


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228254/problem-migrating-connectnamedpipe-from-xp-to-win-7/7243344#7243344